# Как скрипт из тега документа ht перенести в файл js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет нашел на одном сайте готовый прелоадер, но он весь встраивается в html, я решил кинуть все по отдельным файлам, стили получилось скинуть в отдельный файл css, а javaScript не работает. что нужно изменить в скрипте что бы заработало в отдельном подключаемом файле js?

```html
<style type="text/css">#hellopreloader>p{display:none;}#hellopreloader_preload{display: block;position: fixed;z-index: 99999;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;min-width: 1000px;background: #86E2D5 url(http://hello-site.ru//main/images/preloads/ball-triangle.svg) center center no-repeat;background-size:98px;}</style>
<div id="hellopreloader"><div id="hellopreloader_preload"></div><p><a href="http://hello-site.ru">Hello-Site.ru. Бесплатный конструктор сайтов.</a></p></div>
<script type="text/javascript">var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload");function fadeOutnojquery(el){el.style.opacity = 1;var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function(){el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;if (el.style.opacity <=0.05){ clearInterval(interhellopreloader);hellopreloader.style.display = "none";}},16);}window.onload = function(){setTimeout(function(){fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);},1000);};</script>
```

```js
var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload");

function fadeOutnojquery(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function() {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.03;
    if (el.style.opacity <= 0.03) {
      clearInterval(interhellopreloader);
      hellopreloader.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 16);
}
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);
  }, 300);
};
```

Comment: Убрать тэги `<script>`.

Comment: теги скрипт были убраны сразу, в файле script.js находится этот код:                                   var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload");function fadeOutnojquery(el){el.style.opacity = 1;var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function(){el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.03;if (el.style.opacity <=0.03){ clearInterval(interhellopreloader);hellopreloader.style.display = "none";}},16);}window.onload = function(){setTimeout(function(){fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);},300);};

Comment: так покажите, как выглядит содержимое файла и его подключение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что js файл включается в заголовке страницы.

```js
function fadeOutnojquery(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function() {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.03;
    if (el.style.opacity <= 0.03) {
      clearInterval(interhellopreloader);
      el.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 16);
}
window.onload = function() {
  var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload"); // !!!
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);
  }, 300);
};
```

Comment: Заработало, благодарю.

Comment: @ПавелРыбакин На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.